# More efficient way to search documents on mongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

My documents are stored this way:

```
_id: 5ea9f7bae7da54cabbc0b75e
date: 2018-01-27T00:00:00.000+00:00
vehicleid: 32028
points: Array[]
```

And i need just to show the size of the array of each document, I'm using the following pymongo query:

```
{
      "$group": {
        "_id": {
          "vehicleid": "$vehicleid",
          "date": "$date"
        },
        "count": { "$sum": { "$size": "$points" } }
      }
    }
```

**There is any query there is more efficient (faster execution)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why are you using `$group`, when you just want the size of the array field `` for each document. You just need to use the `$size` operator.

```js
db.collection.aggregate({
  "$project": {
    "count": {
      "$size": "$points"
    }
  }
})
```